# ¿Por qué se llama "camello" a la persona que vende drogas?

Tags: etimología, definiciones, animales

La segunda acepción de [camello](https://dle.rae.es/camello?) en el Diccionario de la Lengua es:

> 2. m. coloq. Persona que vende drogas tóxicas al por menor.

que no parece guardar ninguna relación con el resto de las acepciones de camello.

¿Cómo se originó está acepción, que parece ser relativamente moderna?

Answer (score 0):

> El empleo de camello como sinónimo de traficante de drogas a pequeña escala tiene su origen en una picaresca que se extendió entre los vendedores de los años veinte del siglo pasado. Cuando intuían una situación de peligro o la posibilidad de ser descubiertos por la policía, los traficantes escondían la mercancía debajo de sus ropas, generalmente en la espalda, a la altura de la cintura.

<sub>*Fuente [muyinteresante.es](https://www.muyinteresante.es/curiosidades/26356.html)*</sub>

Comment: ¿En cuál país? pues en Colombia "camello" se refiere a tener un trabajo o a que algo tiene mucha dificultad

Comment: En España un camello es un expendedor de drogas

Comment: La persona que hizo la pregunta desapareció.